# How to remove a certain amount of characters from a string

Tags: python, geolocation, geocoder

In python, I am making a virtual assistant. I am working on a way to get the current location of your device and display the weather in that location. Getting the location works fine. I store that data in a variable and print it, but the module I am using displays a bunch of extra information that I don't want. How can I trim off the extra characters so that it's just the city?
The output is

```
Python: The current weather for <[OK] Ipinfo - Geocode [mycity, mystate, US]> is .
```

And my code is

```
# GeoCoder
import geocoder
g = geocoder.ip('me')
print(g)

# import modules necessary to request data from weather api
import requests
import json

print("""
      Welcome to Python Assistant.
      Check the included documentation for a list of requests.
      You can start by typing in a request.
      """)
while True:
      text = input("$PyASSIST > ") 
      # HELP
      if(text.upper() == "HELP"): 
            print("Python: Check the documentation for help.")
      # HELLO
      elif(text.upper() == "HELLO") or (text.upper() == "HI"): 
            print("Python: Hi! How are you today?")
      elif(text.upper() == "TEST") or (text.upper() == "TEST2"): 
            print("Python: The current weather for " + str(g) + " is " + ".")
      else:
            print("Python: I don't know how to respond to that.")
```

EDIT: Almost accidentally doxxed myself, that would have been bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could try this?

```
myString = 'Python: The current weather for <[OK] Ipinfo - Geocode [mycity, mystate, US]> is .'

myString = myString.split('[')[2].split(',')[0]
```

Output:

```
mycity
```

Comment: Sadly doesn't work

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/237777/Desktop/Files/Python Assistant/assistant.py"
237777@FVHF92DZQ6L4 Python Assistant % /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/237777/Desktop/Files/Python Assistant/assistant.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/237777/Desktop/Files/Python Assistant/assistant.py", line 4, in <module>
    g = city.split('[')[2].split(',')[0]
  File "/Users/237777/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/geocoder/base.py", line 606, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.current_result, name)
AttributeError: 'IpinfoResult' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Maybe try changing to “ g = str(city).split('[')[2].split(',')[0]